# Web site cannot be used while win app is running

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a Windows application that uses the database of a local web site. (VS 2010 Express Edition)
While Win app is running the web site cannot be used.

**ERROR message**: Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. 
**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
**Exception Details**: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

Why? How can I fix this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code?  It looks like a connection string problem.  You might be using SSPI and when it is running as a website, it is using the system account to connect to the DB.

Comment: Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ServiceDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

Comment: I guess John is right, but then the website cannot access DB even when the windows app is not running. Is that the case?

Comment: That looks like vb to me, but no matter.  Are you running your website in IIS or asp.net development server?

Comment: User Instance db cannot be shared across applications. See the section User Instance Scenarios here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx).

Comment: no, when the windows app is not running, the website works. windows app is written in vb, the website is running in IIS development server.

Comment: I'd guess the difference is not between "when web app is running", but as @JohnKoerner suggested "website in IIS vs. asp.net development server" as they would run ASP.Net code under different accounts.

Comment: @PaulaRadu, "IIS development server"? It is either one or another... Which one?

Comment: IIS.. (sorry, i'm a beginner)